# Why image1 is not setting any downloadurl

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update the image1 and image2 in firestore and I am setting the image1 and image2 Firestore url by set state in upload function but when I clicking the save button it's showing dialog box which means it's empty. Now I want to ask why this is showing ?? I try to print image1 and image2  and in terminal it's showing the images url

I am not able to understand what's happening ?

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:finadmin/model/carouseldata.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

class UploadCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  const UploadCarousel({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UploadCarousel> createState() => _UploadCarouselState();
}

class _UploadCarouselState extends State<UploadCarousel> {
  File? localimag;
  String? localname;

  File? localimag2;
  String? localname2;
  
  Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

  CollectionReference collectionReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Carousel');

  String image1 = "";
  String image2 = "";

  saveCarousal(BuildContext context) async {
    if (image1.isNotEmpty && image2.isNotEmpty) {
      CarouselImages images = CarouselImages(image1, image2);

      uploadImage1(localimag!, localname!);
      uploadImage2(localimag2!, localname2!);
      await collectionReference
          .doc("RFBNif8jKy24SsNjCuNY")
          .update(images.toMap())
          .then((value) => print("UPDATED FILE     "));
    } else {
      showCupertinoDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return CupertinoAlertDialog(
                title: Text('Field required'),
                content: Text("Song File and Song Name are required"),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text('OK'))
                ]);
          });
    }
  }

  Future imagepicker1() async {
    FilePickerResult? result =
        await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.image);

    if (result != null) {
      File file = File(result.files.first.path!);
      String fileName = result.files.first.name;

      setState(() {
        localimag = file;
        localname = fileName;
      });
    }
  }

  uploadImage1(File file, String fileName) async {
    storageReference
        .child("Images/$fileName")
        .putFile(file)
        .then((firebaseFile) async {
      String imageDownloadUrl = await firebaseFile.ref.getDownloadURL();

      setState(() {
        image1 = imageDownloadUrl;
      });
    });

    print("SUCCESS");
  }

  Future imagepicker2() async {
    FilePickerResult? result =
        await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.image);

    if (result != null) {
      File file = File(result.files.first.path!);
      String fileName = result.files.first.name;

      setState(() {
        localimag2 = file;
        localname2 = fileName;
      });
    }
  }

  uploadImage2(File file, String fileName) async {
    storageReference
        .child("ImageBytes/$fileName")
        .putFile(file)
        .then((firebaseFile) async {
      String imageDownloadUrl2 = await firebaseFile.ref.getDownloadURL();

      setState(() {
        image2 = imageDownloadUrl2;
      });
    });

    print("SUCCESS");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 28, 31, 1),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 55, 15, 25),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                "Upload Carousel ",
                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 23,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(175, 175, 175, 1),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    imagepicker1();
                  },
                  child: localimag != null
                      ? Image.file(
                          localimag!,
                          height: 208,
                          width: 302,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                      : Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(175, 175, 175, 1),
                          )),
                          height: 208,
                          width: 302,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.add,
                                size: 30,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 10),
                              Text(
                                "Upload Carousel 1",
                                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(175, 175, 175, 1),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5),
                              Text(
                                "(recommended min size :  352x258)",
                                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(175, 175, 175, 1),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 25),
              Center(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    imagepicker2();
                  },
                  child: localimag2 != null
                      ? Image.file(
                          localimag2!,
                          height: 208,
                          width: 302,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                      : Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(175, 175, 175, 1),
                          )),
                          height: 208,
                          width: 302,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.add,
                                size: 30,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 10),
                              Text(
                                "Upload Carousel 2",
                                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(175, 175, 175, 1),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5),
                              Text(
                                "(recommended min size :  352x258)",
                                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(175, 175, 175, 1),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 12),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 27, 23, 12),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 12,
                          vertical: 10,
                        ),
                        side: const BorderSide(
                          width: 0.841028,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.42),
                        ),
                        primary: Color.fromRGBO(0, 255, 181, 1),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Save", //text
                        style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                          textStyle: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        saveCarousal(context); //buttonpress
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the saveCarousal method you have written:

```
    if (image1.isNotEmpty && image2.isNotEmpty)
```

Although the condition should be:

```
    if(localimag.isNotEmpty && localimag2.isNotEmpty)
```

Comment: But it's a File? type

Comment: You can check the length of the file in this condition